# How to change the style property of anchor tag inside a Panel?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, panel, anchor

I have added an anchor tag in a Panel as

```
formListPanel.add({
        xtype: 'component',
        autoEl: {
            tag: 'a',
            href: 'javascript: _addTab(\'' + appName + '\', \''+ formName + '\')',
            html: formName,
            style: 'position:absolute;left:'+left+';top:'+top
        }
    })
```

I added many tags like this by changing *left* and *top* variables.

Now I want to change the style of every tag.

I used

```
formListPanel.items.each(function(item){
        item.autoEl.style = 'position:absolute;left:'+left+';top:'+top;
    })
```

But I think we can't just assign the value and expect it to be reflected.
Please tell me how to change the value of the style property. I didn't find any *setStyle* function too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`item.el.applyStyles('position:absolute;left:'+left+';top:'+top);`

This works fine

Answer (score 0):

autoEl is only used for creation.

```
item.el.dom.style = 'position:absolute;left:'+left+';top:'+top;
```

Comment: item.el.applyStyles('position:absolute;left:'+left+';top:'+top);
is working